# Active admin shows html code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm using ejholmes Active_admin Editor and it's working fine but in my active admin index I see the html code with tags and not the correct output. I do use .html_safe in my views but here's my active admin's posts.rb

```
...
index.do
    column :id
    column "Titolo", :title
    column "Corpo news", :body
    column "Creato il", :created_at
    column "Modificato il", :updated_at
    column :link
    column "Link Immagine", :image_url
    bool_column :attivo
    default_actions 
end
...
```

I want to have my "Corpo news" column rendered.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use the method .to_html as you can see by the [source](https://github.com/ejholmes/active_admin_editor/blob/master/app/inputs/html_editor_input.rb)
So in the view you need to call

> body.to_html